# Springboot JPA join columns as entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two domains:

GameMode and Game.

A column of game mode is the game_id, that is a foreign key for Game.

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "game")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class Game extends BaseTable implements Serializable {

    // PROPERTIES
    @Id
   @GeneratedValue()
   @Column(name = "id")
   private UUID id;

   ...
```

I would like to get the entity Game inside the GameMode, as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "game_mode")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class GameMode extends BaseTable implements Serializable {

    // PROPERTIES
    @Id
   @GeneratedValue()
   @Column(name = "id")
   private UUID id;

   @JoinColumn(name="id")
   @Column(name = "game_id")
   private Game game;

   ...
```

But when I try to do this call:

```
GameMode gameMode = gameModeRepository.findByGameAndDescription(game, reqBody.getDescription());
```

(where game is of type Game)

I get this error:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
>   not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:280)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:254)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)\r\n\tat
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.findByGameAndDescription(Unknown
>   Source)\r\n\tat
>   com.ebattlez.core.controller.GameModeController.addGameMode(GameModeController.java:46)\r\n\tat
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)\r\n\tat
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat
>   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:130)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\r\n\tat
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat
>   java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\r\nCaused by:
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2287)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2045)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2007)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2810)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2792)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2624)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2619)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1410)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1558)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1526)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1574)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:111)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:353)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)\r\n\t...
>   95 more\r\nCaused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR:
>   operator does not exist: uuid = bytea\n  Hint: No operator matches the
>   given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type
>   casts.\n  Position: 313\r\n\tat
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2497)\r\n\tat
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2233)\r\n\tat
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:310)\r\n\tat
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:446)\r\n\tat
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:370)\r\n\tat
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:149)\r\n\tat
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:108)\r\n\tat
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)\r\n\tat
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)\r\n\tat
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)\r\n\t...
>   125 more\r\n

Do you know how to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So every time you refer one Entity to another, you have to think if it is a Many-to-One / One-To-One / One-To-Many / Many-To-Many relationship, same thinking when designing the databases.

And you need to specify through annotations to JPA how did you map this in the database.

I will assume that in your case, **One** game can have **Many** Game Modes.
So:

- **One** (game) to **many** (Game Modes)
- **Many** (game modes) to **One** (Game) --> this is what you are trying to map

So in your GameMode class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "game_mode")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class GameMode extends BaseTable implements Serializable {

   // PROPERTIES
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue()
   @Column(name = "id")
   private UUID id;

   @ManyToOne // this will map game_id(game_mode) to id from (game)
   private Game game;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed `@ManyToOne` in the above of relation to Game. So change GameMode as this:

```
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="id")
   @Column(name = "game_id")
   private Game game;
```